# Is there a web-based log-tailing application?

Tags: logging

I have been using BareTail for low-footprint log reading, and it works wonderfully. In particular, I like that it can consume very large large files, detect changes to those files, all without consuming much memory at all.

I'd like to know if there are applications out there -- flash, java applet, etc -- that I could use in a web page to mimic this functionality in a program I'm writing.

What I hope to achieve is the ability to consume log files on a server inside the firewall and display them on a web page, in a semi-streaming fashion. As I said, I'd essentially like to have BareTail in a browser

Answer (score 5):

[Tailon](https://github.com/gvalkov/tailon) is a simplistic web interface to `tail -f` and `tail -f | {grep,awk,sed}`. In this regard, it is very similar to [clarity](https://github.com/tobi/clarity) (I wrote tailon as a safer and more modern alternative to clarity). [Log.io](http://logio.org/) is another modern log file viewer that fits your description.

Comment: Log.io looks good if you're into node.js but the url is http://logio.org/ but SO won't let me edit the link in the answer

Answer (score 2):

[clarity](http://github.com/tobi/clarity) is a newer project which does this and looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

Check vsConsole http://www.vamonossoftware.com/vsconsole

Comment: vsConsole 2.0.3-snapshot is available now, which adds features requested from users. https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0B9pO6BCz4ndtVl90NDJQdUtvNTQ/edit?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most common way to send discrete items of news to a browser is an RSS feed.  A javascript feed parser should sort it out.  Or just use an aggregator server-side.  Depends on your exact needs really; you'd be better posting a description of what you're trying to achieve, rather than how you think you'll achieve it.

Edit: thanks for the update.  For what you want, I'd suggest using something like rsyslog to log into a mysql database, and then just having a php script to query the latest records, and print them, generating an HTML or RSS file.  rsyslog should maintain the database nicely (maybe with the help of cron jobs), and any decent distro will have packages which sets most of this up for you.

Comment: "what i'm trying to achieve" added. thanks.

Comment: thanks for the thoughts, Lee. I'm sure I could whip up a program myself to do this without much fuss. I was really looking for pre-built, drop-in solutions if they existed. I'm finding though that such an application probably does not exist, and I'll need to roll one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in security monitoring of your web logs, I would certainly recommend OSSEC ( http://www.ossec.net ). You can use their web interface to see the alerts live via web.

Answer (score 0):

I needed something like this a couple years back, and didn't find anything that fit well. I ended up writing a simple AJAX loop on the client requesting data including a token from the previous response and appending it to the page. This was paired with a script on the server returning data starting from the file position determined by that token.

Answer (score 0):

If you report to syslog, the [Centreon syslog module](http://forge.centreon.com/projects/centreon-syslog) will do what you want.

[Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/product) also provides a web interface.